# Subtracting method returning wrong answer

Tags: java, methods, addition, subtraction

For some reason when I test my "100-50-40" here I am getting "60" instead of "10". All other combinations work, such as "10+20" and "40-20". The problem occurs when I try to subtract multiple numbers in a row. Any ideas?

```
public double add(String exp){
        String left = "";
        String right = "";
        double leftValue = 0;
        double rightValue = 0;
        double answer = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
    {
        if(exp.charAt(i)=='+')
        {
            right = exp.substring(i+1, exp.length());
            leftValue = subtract(left);
            rightValue = add(right);
            answer = leftValue + rightValue;
            return answer;
        }   
        else
        {
            left = left + exp.substring(i,(i+1));

        }
    } // End for loop
    answer = subtract(exp);
    return answer;

} // End add method

//guaranteed there are no addition operators in exp 
public double subtract(String exp){
    String left = "";
    String right = "";
    double leftValue = 0;
    double rightValue = 0;
    double answer = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
    {
        if(exp.charAt(i)=='-')
        {
            right = exp.substring(i+1, exp.length());
            leftValue = Double.parseDouble(left);
            rightValue = subtract(right);
            answer = leftValue - rightValue;
            return answer;
        }   
        else
        {
            left = left + exp.substring(i,(i+1));
        }
    } // End for loop
    answer = Double.parseDouble(exp);
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: I get `90` for `100-50-40` which - given your algorithm - seems to be the expected value?! Note that your algorithm computes `100-(50-40)`, and not `(100-50)-40`, as one might expect.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting 90 because you evaluate 50-40 before subtracting the result from 100.

In this code, you're dividing the expression at the first minus:

```
        right = exp.substring(i+1, exp.length());
        leftValue = Double.parseDouble(left);
        rightValue = subtract(right);
        answer = leftValue - rightValue;
```

The rightValue is "50-40" and the leftValue is 100.

You can address this particular case by finding the *last* minus.

That said, if you eventually want to handle more complex expressions with other operators and grouping, you may find it useful to read more about hand-writing [recursive-descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or using [parser generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler). With a parser generator, you specify the grammar you want, and the tool builds the code to parse it for you. My own favorite parser generator for Java is [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).